# button loading problem (without packages )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

1. I have custom button spinner component which i build:

   ```
    const ButtonSpinner = ({ onPress, title }) => {
        const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
        const loading = state.loading;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ height: 20, width: 300, marginTop: 15, backgroundColor: "red" }}
                onPress={onPress}
                title={title}
            >
                {loading ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={"black"} />
                ) : (
                    <Text>{title}</Text>
                )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
   ```

   export default ButtonSpinner;
2. i have loading state indicator inside use context

   ```
    const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);(//which work perfectlly)
   ```
3. so no i call to the buttonSpinner with async function like this :

   ```
            <ButtonSpinner
            onPress={() =>
                signHandler(localSign, {
                    loginPage,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                })
            }
            title={"TITLE"}
        />
   ```

**the problem:** i have multiple buttonspinnercomponent calls and when i cliced on one button the loader reference to all the "buttonspinner" component. **PICTURE for rexample:**
[before loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDoo4.jpg)

[when loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNzDf.jpg)

**THE QUESTION:** how can i call to show the loader only in the button that i clicked and not in all my buttonSpinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only use the AuthContext loading property to display the loading indicator. In this way, all your buttons' loading depends to one single property. You need to handle the loading property inside the button in a way to show it only if a button is clicked:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ButtonSpinner = ({ onPress, title }) => {
     const [localLoading, setLocalLoading] = useState(false);
     const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
     const loading = state.loading;
     
     useEffect(() => {
         if (!loading) setLocalLoading(false);
     }, [loading]);

     const onButtonPress = () => {
         setLocalLoading(true);
         onPress();
     }

     return (
         <TouchableOpacity
             style={{ height: 20, width: 300, marginTop: 15, backgroundColor: "red" }}
             onPress={onButtonPress}
             title={title}
         >
             {(loading && localLoading) ? (
                 <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={"black"} />
             ) : (
                 <Text>{title}</Text>
             )}
         </TouchableOpacity>
     );
};
export default ButtonSpinner;
```

EDIT:

If you want to remove the AuthContext and the onPress does not return a Promise, you can pass a callback to the `onPress` function and update the `localLoading` state:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ButtonSpinner = ({ onPress, title }) => {
     const [localLoading, setLocalLoading] = useState(false);

     const onButtonPress = () => {
         setLocalLoading(true);
         onPress(() => setLocalLoading(false));
     }

     return (
         <TouchableOpacity
             style={{ height: 20, width: 300, marginTop: 15, backgroundColor: "red" }}
             onPress={onButtonPress}
             title={title}
         >
             {localLoading ? (
                 <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={"black"} />
             ) : (
                 <Text>{title}</Text>
             )}
         </TouchableOpacity>
     );
};
export default ButtonSpinner;
```

And the ButtonSpinner:

```
const handlePress = async (cb) => {
  await signHandler(localSign, {  
    loginPage,
    name,
    email,
    password,
  });
  cb && cb();
}

<ButtonSpinner
  onPress={handlePress}
  title={"TITLE"}
/>
```

This will work on the assumption that `signHandler` is a Promise. If it's not a promise, use the same technique and pass the `cb` to the signHandler and call it when it is completed.

Comment: thanks ! worked perfectly, there is a way to do this without the context?
i tried like this way:
 const onButtonPress = () => {
  setLocalLoading(true);
  onPress().then(setLocalLoading(false));
 };

and this way 
 const onButtonPress = () => {
  setLocalLoading(true);
  onPress()
(setLocalLoading(false));
 };

but its not waiting for the async function.. so the loader not showing

Comment: This probably didn't work because the `onPress()` does not return a promise. I'll include some code in my answer regarding this

Comment: thank u very much ! i stay in your first solution ... seems more readable ! thank again

Comment: No problem :) :)